# Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm just trying to do a little xmll file with its xsd file but i don't understand the errors I get in the w3c code validator.
My xml code is valid. My xsd code was valid but when I checked the code together, I got errors, I found that my errors were that I was using the  even when I only had 1 element. I corrected this. Now my xsd code in not valid anymore (just by erasng the  ) and I can't find why I get this error.

Here is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<List_Of_Skills>
<Skill>
<Name> PHP </Name>
<ID> 1 </ID>
<Description> Able to code in PHP </Description> 
</Skill>

<Skill>
<Name> XML </Name> 
<ID> 2 </ID>
<Description> Able to code in XML </Description>
</Skill>

<Skill> 
<Name> C# </Name > 
<ID> 3 </ID>
<Description> Able to code applications windows or web in C#</Description>
</Skill>

<Skill> 
<Name> JavaScript </Name>
<ID> 4 </ID> 
<Description> Able to create web applications and animations in JavaScript </Description>
</Skill>

<Skill>
<Name> Python </Name>
<ID> 5 </ID>
<Description> Able to code applications in Python </Description>
</Skill>

<Skill>
<Name> Ajax </Name>
<ID> 6 </ID>
<Description> Able to code web applications in Ajax </Description>
</Skill>


</List_Of_Skills>
```

Here is my xsd code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="List_Of_Skills">
<xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Skill">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/> 
        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:integer"/> 
        <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"/> 
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

and here is the error : 
Error - Line 8, 27: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 27; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_List_Of_Skills' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

If someone has any information thank you

Mayeul

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure you have xs:sequence or something else

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="List_Of_Skills">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Skill" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Actually at the first I got <xs:sequence> but when I got it I had other errors : 
Error - Line 10, 8: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 8; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Skill'. No child element is expected at this point.